# Create PolyLines though a loop in Folium / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I try to create multiple lines from a Dataframe in JupyterLab while looping. I have created the following code but every time I try to run it, my Jupyter Notebook crashes and tell me that the Kernel has died. What am I missing here?

```
m = folium.Map(location=[VstBreitengrad, VstLängengrad], max_zoom=20, zoom_start=5)

for index, row in dfFilter.iterrows():

    Breitengrad = row["Breitengrad_x"]
    Längengrad = row["Längengrad_x"]

    coordinates = [
                [Breitengrad, Längengrad],
                [20, 20]
    ]
               
    folium.PolyLine(
            locations=coordinates,
            color="#FF0000",
            weight=5,
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

Breitengrad_x and Längengrad_x are the columns in the dataframe from where I'll get the coordinates. If I hardcode the coordinates like

```
Breitengrad = 50 #row["Breitengrad_x"]
Längengrad = 20 #row["Längengrad_x"]
```

the code runs without a problem. Thanks a lot for your ideas / solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dtype of `Breitengrad_x` is `int64`, `row["Breitengrad_x"]` will give you a value of type `numpy.int64`. That's what may be causing the problem, since your code runs with the hardcoded values.

Tox fix it, try converting the values into regular `int`:

```
    ...
    Breitengrad = int(row["Breitengrad_x"])
    Längengrad = int(row["Längengrad_x"])
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was indeed the problem. I edited it to the following:

    Breitengrad = float(row["Breitengrad_x"])
    Längengrad = float(row["Längengrad_x"])

By this it works like charm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, iterating through pandas objects is generally slow (*see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#iteration)*).

I would suggest you to make a [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) using [`LineString`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.LineString.html) objects, then [`explore`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) them to make a folium [`Map`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/reference.html#folium.folium.Map) :

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        LineString([extremity, ORIGIN])
        for extremity in dfFilter.to_numpy()[:, ::-1]
        # or hardcoded : dfFilter[["Längengrad_x", "Breitengrad_x"]].to_numpy()
    ],
    crs=4326,
)

m = gdf.explore(
    style_kwds={
        "weight": 5, "color": "#FF0000",
    },
    width=700, height=350,
)
```

Output (`m`):

[image]

Used input (`dfFilter`):

```
from shapely import LineString
import geopandas as gpd

ORIGIN = (20, 20) # lon/lat

dfFilter = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Breitengrad_x": [50, 39, 10, 9],
        "Längengrad_x": [20, -2, 3.5, 38],
    }
)
```